# Conda install Spacy - Package missing in current channels

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spacy

I am trying to install Spacy. I was trying to use Pip but I kept getting and error related to C++ build tools (which I downloaded). Now, I am trying to use Conda, running `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` but I get the error shown below.

[image]

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Based on what I've read, this should work.

thanks,

**Update**

I ran `anaconda search -t conda spacy`. This is my output:

[image]

Comment: have you tried with `conda install spacy` ?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that and I got the same results.

Comment: are you sure that you're connected to internet?

Comment: Yes, I am able to post to StackOverflow.

Comment: which conda version you use?

Comment: `conda --version 4.3.24`

Comment: could you run this command on your cmd: `anaconda search -t conda spacy`

Comment: could you share the output?

Comment: I add the output to my question. I after looking over the output, I tried `conda install -c anaconda spacy` . It looks like it's downloading so we'll see if this works.

Comment: glad that it works

Comment: Please do not post terminal output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package seem to be available for Windows 32 in anaconda channels, so try to run :

```
conda install -c anaconda spacy
```